# Rails Generate Model - Changing Model Name after DB:migrate

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I created a model using:

`rails generate model SavingsItem`

I then ran `rake db:migrate`.

Now, I want to rename the model to `SavingsProduct`

I did a rake db:rollback and then went directly into my migration file and change the model name and table name. However, when I run `rake db:migrate` again, it creates the right table name in my database, but creates `savings_item.rb` still.

Why does this happen?

Here is my migration file:

```
class CreateSavingsProducts < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :savings_products do |t|
      t.string :name, :limit => 50
      t.string :description, :limit => 200
      t.decimal :price, :precision => 10, :scale => 2
      t.string :buy_url, :limit => 200
      t.string :image_url, :limit => 200
      t.integer :image_width, :limit => 11
      t.integer :image_height, :limit => 11
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> when I run rake db:migrate again, it creates the right table name in
>   my database, but creates savings_item.rb

Migrations only alter the database; they don't create or alter any files (except schema.rb). Generators are what create and alter files, including migration files.

If you already have the model generated, you can simply change its name manually. Change `class SavingsItem` to `class SavingsProduct` and rename the file from `savings_item.rb` to `savings_product.rb`.

Comment: How do I alter my generator? I did that as a quick fix, but if I'm collaborating with others, this means everyone who runs the migration would have to do this as well.

Comment: No, you missed the point, running the migration will not create any files. When you generate the model it creates multiple files, one of which is the migration - so it's the generate model command that you ran that is to blame, not the migration. Just make sure you modify the files before you push it to whatever means you're using to collaborate, and you won't have to worry.

Comment: (Note: the above comment is assuming you haven't explicitly written File IO commands in the migration that would affect the file system/create files, of course.)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if there's a way to rename a model but you can simply use `destroy` to get rid off a mistakenly named model. like this: `rails destroy model model_name`

destroy deletes all files automatically generated by `generate` command.